# Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise: Load Test, user load loading extremely slow during warm up period

Tags: visual-studio, load-testing

I'm having an issue with load test "warm up" period, the user load is increasing extremely slow or some times does not start ramping up until the warm up period is over with. My test mix includes an initialize test, five run duration test, and a terminate test. The load test pattern is based on user pace. Here is the test mix ratio:

```
[Initialize]
 - Test 1 (0.2 per user per hour)
 - Test 2 (0.1 per user per hour)
 - Test 3 (0.15 per user per hour)
 - Test 4 (0.25 per user per hour)
 - Test 5 (0.1 per user per hour)
 - Test 6 (0.2 per user per hour) 
 - Test 7 (0.125 per user per hour)
[Terminate]

Load Pattern:
 - Initial User Count 1
 - Maximum User Count 100
 - Step Duration 10
 - Step Ramp Time 5
 - Step user Count 20

Run Time:
 - Cool Down 15 mins.
 - Run Duration 1 hour.
 - Warm-up Duration 10 mins.
```

Any help would be most appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Test 1 at 0.2 per user per hour means each user does one test every five hours. The average rate is about 0.16 per user per hour and there are 7 tests. Thus each user does about 7*0.16 tests per hour, so about 1.12 tests per hour.

The ramp starts at 1 user, it increments by 20 users every 10 seconds to reach 100. So it takes 5 increments to reach the maximum. That is less than 1 minute. (The step ramp just says the 20 users start during 5 of the 10 seconds step duration.) Given the test duration is 60 minutes the ramp time has little impact on the number of test executed.

With 100 users executing 1.12 tests each per hour we would expect a total of 112 tests to be executed in one hour. (A small number fewer due to the short ramp up period.) Several tests are likely to be in progress at the end of the hour but there is a 15 minute cool down period.

It is possible that Visual Studio varies the user pace in a similar manner to how it varies think times to simulate the speeds of different real people. I have not found anything definitive about whether times are varied when a user pace is specified. But it could account for the variations that you observe.

To me the small increase in user load you see is reasonable given the small number of tests per user per hour that are specified.

I would have liked to see a value for average test duration in the question. Knowing this can help understand how the tests run.

Comment: Do you think in increase the test per user per hour would rectify the issue of  nothing running during the warm-up period? I do eventually plan on running a load of a 1000 users, so the number of test run per user per hour should increase. My main concern is the warm-up period, the user load is not ramping. I thought using a smaller load size and decreased run times would "debug" the issue. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @JosephFreeman Do the sums or draw the equivalent of the "Virtual user activity chart" on a piece of paper. At the test rate of your scenario there is very little to do. The ramp up is being done but it takes less than one minute.

Comment: @JosephFreeman Is testing based on user pace the correct approach? 1000 user doing very little is much the same as 10 users doing a lot of work. You may be better with a different test mix model.

Comment: I'm quite new to the other test model, run test at a ridiculous rate. I chose this particular mix because it seems to be a more realistic approach, mimicking real world usage. Looking at the Virtual User Activity Chart, the user load does not increase until a minute into the run duration. I was under the assumption that warm-up period can be used to slowly ramp the user load? This doesn't seem to be working. Is there a configuration that I may have missed? My goal is to get the user load to ramp during warm-up, if I can get that working rest of the finer details can be worked out at a later.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding load tests. See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/geoffgr/2013/08/24/explanation-of-v-s-load-test-warm-up-load-patterns-and-cool-down-and-how-this-affects-the-reported-results/ about warm up. Also look carefully at the step pattern of your test and work out how quickly it reaches maximum load; I tried to explain this in my answer.

Comment: Yeah i could have a misunderstanding of how it's working. Thank you for your help!